# flot how to avoid x-axis repeating date values

Tags: flot

I have a flot line graph where the x values are repeating but I can't quite figure out why. How can I fix this?

My x-axis is defined as...

```
  chartOptions = {
    xaxis: {
      mode: "time",
      timeformat: "%d/%m/%y",
      //tickSize: [1, "day"],
      //tickLength: 2
    },
```

And my data is ...

```
[1424005200000,20795],[1424091600000,20151],[1424178000000,22448],[1424264400000,27000],[1424350800000,30622],[1424437200000,30844],[1424523600000,23139]
```

[image]

Comment: The option you have commented out `//tickSize: [1, "day"],` will fix this.  Example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/rrrlt8h7Is6zTtHrPl5c?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked. I had it commented out because the dates were not matching points on the graph. But i've since found out that was a timezone offset issue. So what exactly is a tick in flot speak? I've been trying to look up the documentation on this but can't get a good understanding of what a tick is and what changing the size actually means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `minTickSize: [1,"day"]`
So the day will appear once in the graph.

```
 chartOptions = {
        xaxis: {
          mode: "time",
          timeformat: "%d/%m/%y",
          minTickSize: [1,"day"],
          //tickLength: 2
        },
```